# Grepping only SSH connections with netstat

Tags: ssh, networking, grep, security

I have some commands added to my `.bashrc`, so every time I log in I can see active SSH connections. However, it sometimes shows more than just SSH connections due to a similar port number containing "22", e.g. "223346"

This is the command that is ran:

```
netstat -tan | grep ":22\|ssh" | grep -v "LISTEN" | awk '{print "     "$4" -> "$5"      "$6}'
```

Sometimes it outputs stuff like this:

```
192.168.1.75:52623 -> 213.174.2.30:22650   SYN_SENT
192.168.1.75:22 -> 192.168.1.109:60561     ESTABLISHED
```

Is there a way of using grep to ONLY show SSH connections? Thanks!

Comment: Would adding a delimiter like `grep ':22\>` help?

Comment: add a space or word boundary after `:22`? and no need grep... `awk '/:22 |ssh/ && !/LISTEN/{print ...}'`

Comment: `netstat -ta | grep ssh`

Comment: Thank you all! Using Sundeeps suggestion has worked perfectly.

Comment: `netstat` now obsolete, per man page.  Take a look at `ss` - https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss

Comment: Jack, did either of the answers solve your problem? If so, please use the checkmark to tell the system that the question is Answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If on Linux, note that the man page of `ss` has an example exactly for that:

```
ss -o state established '( dport = :ssh or sport = :ssh )'
```

See also

```
lsof -i tcp:22
```

Or:

```
lsof -i :53
```

(tcp or any other transport protocol).

Note however that `lsof` will not list information for the processes you don't own if you're not superuser.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it with this test:

- an ESTABLISHED connection, and
- include either *incoming* (field 3's port is 22) or *outbound* (field 4's port is 22) connections -- here anchored between the `:` and the end of the field `$`.

You could adjust the logic to include *either* incoming or outbound, if that's what you're after.

If you use netstat's `-n` flag, then you don't have to search for "ssh"; to be more granular and request that only the ports be numeric (on Linux) while trying to resolve the IPs, use `--numeric-ports`.  I also dropped the `-a` netstat flag, to filter out the "LISTEN" lines (since they're not connected to another endpoint). Since I'm only printing established connections, I also dropped field 6 ("ESTABLISHED") from the output; that's easy enough to add back, either statically or dynamically.

```
netstat -n | awk '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && ($3 ~ /:22$/ || $4 ~ /:22$/) { print $4 " -> " $5}'
```

or

```
netstat --numeric-ports | awk '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && ($3 ~ /:22$/ || $4 ~ /:22$/) { print $4 " -> " $5}'
```