# Extracting IP from IP.port

Tags: sed, regular-expression, qnx

I've done a lot of digging but haven't found an answer to my problem.

Currently, I have the following command:

```
netstat | grep telnet | grep ESTABLISHED | awk 'NR==1{ print $5}'
```

Which returns something like this:

```
192.168.15.73.64759
```

From this, I want to get just the IP without the port. So,

```
192.168.15.73
```

The system I'm doing this on runs an embedded Unix variant (QNX) and does not support -o as an option to grep.  The system supports sed which is likely the best route, but I'm unfamiliar with that application.

Can anyone tell me what I could add to get the output I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cut` or `sed`:

```
echo 192.168.15.73.64759 | cut -d '.'  -f 1-4 
echo 192.168.15.73.64759 | sed -E 's,\.[0-9]+$,,'
```

Or `awk`:

```
echo 192.168.15.73.64759 | awk -F '.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, the system does not have cut nor does it support the -E option for sed.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, I found -E is equivalent to -r which is supported by my system.  sed -r 's,\.[0-9]+$,,' provided me with the output I was looking for!

Comment: BTW, what system is that? I guess it's something even more simple than `busybox`?

Comment: It's running a proprietary OS called QNX.

Answer (score 1):

Having just [learned about ss](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381162/117549):

```
ss -n -o state established '( dport = :telnet or sport = :ssh )' | 
  awk  'NR==2 { print substr($5, 1, index($5, ":")-1) }'
```

I use NR==2 to skip past the header and grab only the first line of output, to corresponding with your netstat/grep behavior. The rest of the awk code prints $5, but starting from the first character and only going until the index where ":" is found, minus one.

If the system is missing `ss`, then you can use sed:

```
echo 192.168.15.73.64759 | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'

netstat | grep telnet | grep ESTABLISHED | awk 'NR==1{ print $5}' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'
```

This replaces "period followed by zero or more digits followed by the end of the line" with "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Use string substitution:

```
$ IP=192.168.15.73.64759
$ echo ${IP%.*}
192.168.15.73
```

---

```
IP=$(netstat | grep telnet | grep ESTABLISHED | awk 'NR==1{ print $5}')
echo ${IP%.*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying a single `awk` command to the output of `netstat` would be enough to capture any line that contains the sub-strings `ESTABLISHED` and `telnet` and then output a trimmed 5th field.

```bash
netstat | awk '/ESTABLISHED/ && /telnet/ { sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",$5); print $5 }'
```

If you need only the first result, change `print $5` to `print $5; exit` in the `awk` code, or pass it through `head -n 1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
netstat | grep telnet | grep ESTABLISHED | awk 'NR==1{ print $5}' |grep -Po "\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b"
```

Comment: I don't think that a simple, embedded system would have `-P`. `busybox` does not for example.

Comment: The question mentions that `grep -o` does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do that using `grep -E`

```
in="192.168.15.73.64759"

echo $in | grep -Eo "([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){4}" | grep -Po "(.*)(?=\.$)"

~#: 192.168.15.73
```

the -E allows extended regex, and -P for Perl compatible to include the last dot in the pattern but excluding it from the output

Comment: The question mentions that `grep -o` does not work.